# Resize donut chart that's using SVG circles whilst maintaining the proportions of the segments

Tags: html, svg

I am [following a tutorial](https://medium.com/@heyoka/scratch-made-svg-donut-pie-charts-in-html5-2c587e935d72) which goes into details on creating donut charts using SVG circles and strokes.

However, am struggling to work out how I can resize the final object to any size to my liking, for example, I want the donut chart to scale fully to whatever the svg element is set to (in this case 500x500).

My goal is to start off at 500x500 donut chart and resize later (based on the presence of css class) to 50x50

This is the basic code (but see jsfiddle for the whole thing)

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
  <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
  <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>

  <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#ce4b99" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="40 60" stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
  <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="20 80" stroke-dashoffset="85"></circle>
  <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#377bbc" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="30 70" stroke-dashoffset="65"></circle>
  <!-- unused 10% -->
  <g class="chart-text">
    <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-number">
      10
    </text>
    <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-label">
      Beers
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BrightPixels/99symn4L/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple.  Just define a different size for your `<div>` in a CSS class.

```
<div class="donut-chart">
</div>

<div class="donut-chart small">
</div>


.donut-chart {
  width: 500px;
}

.donut-chart.small {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Demo:

```css
.donut-chart {
  width: 500px;
}

.donut-chart.small {
  width: 100px;
}



    html {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    *, *:before, *:after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
    }
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400);

    .chart-text {
      font: 16px/1.4em "Montserrat", Arial, sans-serif;
      fill: #000;
      -moz-transform: translateY(0.25em);
      -ms-transform: translateY(0.25em);
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0.25em);
      transform: translateY(0.25em);
    }

    .chart-number {
      font-size: 0.6em;
      line-height: 1;
      text-anchor: middle;
      -moz-transform: translateY(-0.25em);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-0.25em);
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.25em);
      transform: translateY(-0.25em);
    }

    .chart-label {
      font-size: 0.2em;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-anchor: middle;
      -moz-transform: translateY(0.7em);
      -ms-transform: translateY(0.7em);
      -webkit-transform: translateY(0.7em);
      transform: translateY(0.7em);
    }
```

```html
  <div class="donut-chart">

    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
      <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
      <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>

      <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#ce4b99" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="40 60" stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
      <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="20 80" stroke-dashoffset="85"></circle>
      <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#377bbc" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="30 70" stroke-dashoffset="65"></circle>
      <!-- unused 10% -->
      <g class="chart-text">
        <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-number">
          10
        </text>
        <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-label">
          Beers
        </text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="donut-chart small">

    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
      <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
      <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>

      <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#ce4b99" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="40 60" stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
      <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#b1c94e" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="20 80" stroke-dashoffset="85"></circle>
      <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#377bbc" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="30 70" stroke-dashoffset="65"></circle>
      <!-- unused 10% -->
      <g class="chart-text">
        <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-number">
          10
        </text>
        <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-label">
          Beers
        </text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

Comment: In your examples, svg is sized as 500x500 but the circles/donuts are smaller at 378.49x378.49. There seems to be some "padding" between the svg element and circle elements.

Comment: That's because your `viewBox` is 42 wide and high, but your circles are smaller than that (r=15). If you want to reduce the padding, adjust the `viewBox`.

Comment: Thank you. It's the viewbox I didn't understand.

Comment: There are very good articles on the web that explain the viewBox, and it is a little complicated to summarize in a comment.  But basically it describes the area of the SVG that you want to be visible in the viewPort (the area described by `width` and `height`). If the `viewBox` is wider or heigher than the bounds of your shape, then that extra space be visible in your viewport area.  That is the case for you.  If you want to lose the extra space, either make your graph circles bigger, or make your viewBox dimensions more snug to the circles. Eg.: `viewBox="3.5 3.5 35 35"`

Comment: Thank you. I read a lot of viewBox and it was a little too much. What helped me for my purpose, is to think of the svg element as the entire film scene and viewBox height and width (the last two figures) as the camera zoom level control. If I want the circle to fill the whole screen, then I should zoom in as much as the size of the circle. This helped me but am sure there is more to viewBox.